# Иконка приложения в PyQt

Tags: python, pyqt, qt-designer, qrc, qicon

Я создал простой интерфейс в *Qt Designer* с иконкой в рамке окна.

При предпросмотре интерфейса иконка отображается. 
После конвертации **`.ui`** в **`.py`** при помощи *`pyuic5`* и запуске кода иконка отображаться перестала.

С чем это может быть связано и как можно решить эту проблему? 
Заранее, спасибо!

Снизу минимальная рабочая версия:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(":/icons/icon.ico"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        MainWindow.setWindowIcon(icon)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_2)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

Ваше изображение находится в файле ресурсра **имя.qrc**, 
например **resources.qrc**

1. Вам надо выполнить:

   `pyrcc5 resources.qrc -o resources_rc.py`                   # <----
2. Импортировать модуль **`resources_rc.py`** в вашем **`main.py`**

```
    from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
    import resource_rc                                        # <----

    class Ui_MainWindow(object):
        ...
```

3. Все, запускайте **main.py**

Comment: @Роман я ответил на ваш вопрос?